# There is no row at position 0;

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

Help I keep getting this error when I try to get the specific data of score in my row.

I have this data in my database:

```
PlayerName    Score
qwe            20
keith          0
```

I have this code in winform:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Rogue;Initial Catalog=SoftProject;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
  try
  {
    String str1 = "";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerName,Score from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", txtPlayer.Text);
        DataTable dataTable= new DataTable();
        dataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        if(dataTable.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            // concatenate the two string and get the table score row
            str1 = String.Concat(str1, (dataTable.Rows[0]["Score"].ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            //Report error
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
  }
  catch()
  {
     MessageBox.Show("No data");
  }
}
```

In this code here, this keeps my system get an error:

```
str1 = String.Concat(str1, (dataTable.Rows[0]["Score"].ToString()));
```

getting the name and score of 'qwe' and '20' is ok;
but in the 2nd column 'keith' and '0'. 
My code flag me to an error "There is no row at position 0";

What seems to be the problem of the string.concat method()?

Comment: It is a problem of `datatable.Rows[0]` not string.concat. Make sure your query returns data in your datatable for name 'Keith'

Comment: It's not a problem with that method. Your SQL query just isn't returning any data, so you don't have any rows in the table. Also, if you are just loading data from the database, don't use `DataTable`, it is very inefficient. Just use `IDataReader`.

Comment: or use the .Fill Method or check out MSDN link for the [DataTable.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsze9wte(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: so you have executed the reader & load in dt & you are trying to get the value from dataTable & not dt.

Comment: @Nikita yes sir, just to get the data "Score" in my table,

Comment: @LaurenceAlbano so u are aware that you have two different objects.(dataTable & dt), right?

Comment: Shouldn't this be dt.Rows[0] instead of dataTable.Rows[0]?

Comment: I've edited my code above sir, dt supposed to be dataTable, if I will change it to DataReader is it possible make this code correct?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen do you have some examples or link about efficient way to use SqlDataReader sir? It would be helpful.

Comment: @LaurenceAlbano Basically you just take what `ExecuteReader()` returns, in the case of a single row you `if (reader.Read()) { string val = reader.GetString(0) }` etc. Very simple and you can find many examples of it on the internet. For several rows you just `while (reader.Read())`. And remember to `Close()` it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Rogue;Initial Catalog=SoftProject;Integrated Security=True"))
{
conn.Open();
try
{
String str1 = "";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerName,Score from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", txtPlayer.Text);
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
    {
        // concatenate the two string and get the table score row
        str1 += ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Score"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        //Report error
    }
    }

    conn.Close();
  }
  catch()
  {
     MessageBox.Show("No data");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

USing only SqlDatareader is sufficient

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Rogue;Initial Catalog=SoftProject;Integrated Security=True"))
        {           
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                String str1 = "";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerName,Score from PlayerData where PlayerName = @player", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player", txtPlayer.Text);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if(reader.Read())
                    {
                        str1 = String.Concat(str1, reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Score")));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: If you are sure that it returns only one row, use if condition. If multiple rows are returned, Use a while loop and read each row. while(reader.Read() { reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Score"))})

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
str1 = String.Concat(str1, (dataTable.Rows[0]["Score"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: I've already try this code sir, (see from edit above) but the condition goes to the catch method and reports no data.

Comment: What is the row count that you are getting ?

Comment: The 2nd row of Score sir `0`

Comment: try this and tell me the value of RowCount

int RowCount=datatable.Rows.Count;

if the value of the RowCount variable is 0 then your query doesnot return any rows .

Comment: RowCount does not contain built it function, does `RowCount` declaration is an int? ,, is it okay to edit your code above sir?

Comment: The system still prompts me an error sir, it will go directly to the else statement and catch condition.

Comment: If it goes to the catch condition then your SQL query does not return any rows.